# HTML Checkbox automatically send POST

Tags: html, post, checkbox, methods

I'm trying to collect checkbox data without adding button to submit.

This is the code I have so far:

```html
          <!-- Web form -->
            <form class="switcher-form" method="post">
    <p class="setting-switch setting-switch-first">
     <label for="setting1">Controle Total</label>
     <!-- switcher checkbox #1 -->
     <input type="checkbox" class="switcher" checked name="setting1" value="1" onclick="submit();"/>
    </p>
    
    <p class="setting-switch">
     <label for="setting2">Controle Sala</label>
     <!-- switcher checkbox #2 -->
     <input type="checkbox" class="switcher" checked name="setting2" value="2" onclick="submit();"/>
    </p>

    <p class="setting-switch">
     <label for="setting3">Controle Quarto A</label>
     <!-- switcher checkbox #3 -->
     <input type="checkbox" class="switcher" checked name="setting3" value="3" onclick="submit();"/>
    </p>
    
    <p class="setting-switch">
     <label for="setting4">Controle Quarto B</label>
     <!-- switcher checkbox #4 -->
     <input type="checkbox" class="switcher" checked name="setting4" value="4" onclick="submit();"/>
    </p>
    
    <p class="setting-switch">
     <label for="setting5">Controle Cozinha</label>
     <!-- switcher checkbox #5 -->
     <input type="checkbox" class="switcher" checked name="setting5" value="5" onclick="submit();"/>
    </p>

    <p class="setting-switch">
     <label for="setting6">Controle Garagem</label>
     <!-- switcher checkbox #6 -->
     <input type="checkbox" class="switcher" checked name="setting6" value="6" onclick="submit();"/>
    </p>

    <p class="setting-switch">
     <label for="setting7">Controle Portao</label>
     <!-- switcher checkbox #7 -->
     <input type="checkbox" class="switcher" checked name="setting7" value="7" onclick="submit();"/>
    </p>

    <p class="setting-switch">
     <label for="setting8">Controle Refrigeracao</label>
     <!-- switcher checkbox #8 -->
     <input type="checkbox" class="switcher" checked name="setting8" value="8" onclick="submit();"/>
    </p>
            </form>
            <!-- End: Web form -->
```

Is it possible to use method to POST or GET? Automatically send the the checkbox, ex: http://index.htm?setting1=0

I'm not really good with CSS HTML JS, this code is running on microcontroller.

Comment: So you want to send data to the server whenever the user clicks on the checkbox?

Comment: Yes, thats it, whenever the checkbox change I want to send the data to server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to add an [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick) event to the checkbox, so that a Javascript function can contact the server in the background via an [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), as illustrated below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
"use strict"

function doAJAX()
{

  console.log("Contacting the server...");

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function()
  {
    console.log("Got a response!");
  };
  xhr.open("get", "http://localhost:3000/something.png", true);
  xhr.responseType = "blob";
  xhr.send();

}
    </script>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="doAJAX();">
  </body>
</html>
```

Bear in mind that you may need to consider [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) if you're sending/receiving to a different domain.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I couldn't get it to work. I wish i could have in my server a request like this:

"GET /index.htm?setting1=0 HTTP/1.1"

Comment: Simply change the `xhr.open("get", "http://localhost:3000/something.png", true);` line. The first parameter is already set as `get` so you simply need to replace the `http://localhost:3000/something.png` part with the URL that you want to send the request to. Don't worry about the `HTTP/1.1` part - that's taken care of for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is great information to solve this problem:

[image]

http://startingelectronics.com/tutorials/arduino/ethernet-shield-web-server-tutorial/web-server-read-switch-automatically-using-AJAX/

Comment: This simply connects to the server once per second, rather than whenever a checkbox is clicked. Be aware that the server will potentially have to deal with many more (spurious) requests this way, especially if a lot of users are viewing the page.